# how to solve a an Error String Index out of range in a function on a customtkinter gui that use sqlite3 as db?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI using customtkinter, tkinter, and sqlite3. I have a function where you need to select an item on a treeview and click a button to access the database and change a cell in a boolean column. However, I'm encountering an issue when selecting the item on the treeview and clicking the button. At that moment, the error 'STRING INDEX OUT OF RANGE' appears. My database has 13 columns,maybe this info can help.

I'm using this function to perform the task I described. However, as I mentioned, instead of selecting the cell and opening a new window to make changes in the database, it is giving me the error 'String index out of range

```
    def alugar_veiculos(self):

        self.mensagem['text'] = ''  # Mensagem inicialmente vazia
        try:
            self.tabela.item(self.tabela.selection())['text'][0]
        except IndexError as e:
            print(e)
            self.mensagem['text'] = 'Por favor, selecione um Veículo'
            return
        #nome = self.tabela.item(self.tabela.selection())['text']
        #old_preco = self.tabela.item(self.tabela.selection())['values'][0]

        self.janela_alugar = Toplevel()  # Criar uma janela à frente da principal
        self.janela_alugar.title = 'Alugar Veículo'  # Titulo da janela
        self.janela_alugar.resizable(1, 1)
        self.janela_alugar.wm_iconbitmap('recursos/steering-wheel.ico')
```

traceback:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\ProjetoFinal\venv\Lib\site-packages\customtkinter\windows\widgets\ctk_button.py", line 554, in _clicked
    self._command()
  File "C:\Users\Gabriel\PycharmProjects\ProjetoFinal\app.py", line 313, in alugar_veiculos
    self.tabela.item(self.tabela.selection())['text'][0]
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: It looks like `self.tabela.item(self.tabela.selection())['text']` is an empty string, and therefore it does not have a `[0]` index.

Comment: Please provide a whole traceback so we don't guess which line causes the error

Comment: I'm sorry, my friend! I'm new! I put the traceback now

Comment: Post the traceback as text instead of a linked image.  Also it is better to provide a [mre] instead of incomplete block of code.